# Ionic 3 get index of clicked item

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework

I need to get the index of the clicked item in an ion list, so I can access the position in an array.

The html code I used is this:

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-item *ngFor="let poi of poiList" (click)="openPage(poi, $index)">
 <h2> {{ poi.name }} </h2>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Inside the function `openPage` I've printed the index in the console, but it is showed as "undefined". I couldn't find any other way to get the index correctly.

Answer (score 8):

`$index` will only work for AngularJS, in Angular2 and above the way to get the clicked item index is the following :

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-item *ngFor="let poi of poiList; let i= index" (click)="openPage(poi, i)">
 <h2> {{ poi.name }} </h2>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```